# How to get text from URLs using regexp_extract in data studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

Example URLs:

1. /en/current-season/abc-note-book/2018-abc-note-book-arun-1
2. /en/current-season/xyz-note-book/2018-xyz-note-book-kumar-2
3. /en/current-season/pqr-note-book/2018-pqr-note-book-rahul-3

I want to extract 'abc-note-book' section as column 1 from all the URLs

**Expected Result:**

1. abc note book
2. xyz note book
3. pqr note book

And also need to extract 'arun-1' section as column 2 from all the URLs

**Expected Result**

1. arun-1
2. kumar-2
3. rahul-3

Please suggest how to extract using regexp_extract in data studio? Or is there any other formula to extract it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/395e7b27-e5ab-4e70-9c9d-f9eb8565d8bd) (Google Sheets Embedded) to demonstrate. The required text can be extracted using the [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function, and in the case of Column 1, [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) can be used to replace the - with a space:

> **Column 1 (e.g. abc note book)**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, "/\\d+-(\\w+-\\w+-\\w+)"), "-", " ")
> ```
>
> **Column 2 (e.g. arun-1)**
>
> ```
> REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, "(\\w+-\\d+)$")
> ```

[image]